# Android SMS app ignores a trailing "?" when the URL containing a trailing "?" is clicked

Tags: android, escaping, sms

I send an SMS saying "Click on https://www.example.com/?"

When I receive this SMS on an Android phone, only the https://www.example.com is clickable. The "?" is visible in the SMS, but is not part of the clickable URL.

Is there some way to escape the ? or do some other workaround so that click on the link goes to https://www.example.com/?

EDIT: Forget Android - even on this page on stackoverflow - the "?" is not part of the clickable link

Comment: What's the point of having an empty query string in your URL?

Comment: I have a JSP page which seems to behave a little different with or without the Trailing ? - I still have to figure out why it's so. However, with the trailing "?" - it behaves the way I want it to

Comment: you can remove "?" then fix your JSP page. this is an empty query anyways.

Comment: @user1506104 - if I could do that, then I wouldn't have asked this question at all.

Comment: That is absolutely right. Lol

Comment: How about you try this https://example.com/?version=1.0 Adding extra query parameter shouldn't hurt your application

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to be correct behaviour (as far as I have observed on other systems) - an empty query string (effectively a dangling question mark) is not necessarily part of the URL so appears as punctuation.

As a workaround my suggestion is to ensure you always provide a parameter:

```
https://www.example.com/?a=a
```

Ideally you can find something that makes the link enticing to the user (rather than only confusing):

```
https://www.example.com/?vip=yes
```

Because these are not query parameters you are actually using, they should not affect your page processing

Comment: `an empty query string is not a necessary part of the URL so appears as punctuation.` - do you have a source for this?

Comment: `As a workaround my suggestion is to ensure you always provide a parameter:` - this is what I have done now - is it foolproof?

Comment: "do you have a source for this?" unfortunately not - in fact https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3986 is explicit about treating a URL with and without a dangling character as different. My comments were more anecdotal. I've reworded my answer

Answer (score 3):

Can you replace the question mark (?) by %3F

[www.example.com/%3F](http://www.example.com/%3F)

See:

https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp

Answer (score -1):

Hi you can send by converting to short url by https://goo.gl/ and you can get same as expected .